# Adding custom eloquent attribute in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a function named `siblings` which fetches all siblings of a user.

```
select siblings(id) as `siblings` from users where id = 1
```

I can access the function in Eloquent as

```
User::where('id', 1)->first([DB::raw(siblings(id) as `siblings`)]->siblings;
```

I want to make the `siblings` available via custom attribute.

I added `siblings` to `$appends` array

I also created `getSiblingsAttribute` method in my `User` model as

```
public function getSiblingsAttribute()
{
    if (!$this->exists()) {
        return [];
    }

    $siblings = User::where('idd', $this->id)
        ->first([DB::raw('siblings(id) AS `siblings`')])
        ->siblings;

    return explode(',', $siblings);
}
```

But this is not working as `$this->id` returns `null`

My table schema is `users(id, username,...)`, so clearly `id` is present.

Is there a way by which I can bind the `siblings` function while querying db and then returning something like `$this->siblings` from `getSiblingsAttribute`. If I  can bind `siblings(id) as siblings` with query select globally as we do for scopes using global scope.

That way my code can be simply

```
public function getSiblingsAttribute()
{
    return $this->siblings;
}
```

Comment: It should be `$this->attributes['id']`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create a view in your database and use that as a table:

```php
protected $table = 'user_view';
```

Otherwise I need more information about your `id == null` problem.
If you can fix this by your own in the next step it is important that you use an other column name by selecting as in your accessor otherwise you run in an infinite loop.

```php
public function getSiblingsAttribute()
{
    if (!$this->exists()) {
        return [];
    }

    $siblings = User::where('id', $this->id)
        ->first([DB::raw('siblings(id) AS `siblings_value`')])
        ->siblings_value;

    return explode(',', $siblings);
}
```

**EDIT**

Sadly there is no *simple* way to archieve this.
But after a little bit tinkering I have found a (not very nice) solution.
Give it a try.

You have to add the following class and trait to your app.

`app/Classes/AdditionalColumnsTrait.php` (additional column trait)

```php
namespace App\Classes;


trait AdditionalColumnsTrait {

    public function newEloquentBuilder($query) {
        $builder = new EloquentBuilder($query);
        $builder->additionalColumns = $this->getAdditionalColumns();

        return $builder;
    }

    protected function getAdditionalColumns() {
        return [];
    }
}
```

`app/Classes/EloquentBuilder.php` (extended EloquentBuilder)

```php
namespace App\Classes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class EloquentBuilder extends Builder {

    public $additionalColumns = [];

    public function getModels($columns = ['*']) {
        $oldColumns = is_null($this->query->columns) ? [] : $this->query->columns;
        $withTablePrefix = $this->getModel()->getTable() . '.*';
        if (in_array('*', $columns) && !in_array($withTablePrefix, $oldColumns)) {

            $this->query->addSelect(array_merge($columns, array_values($this->additionalColumns)));
        } elseif (in_array($withTablePrefix, $oldColumns)) {
            $this->query->addSelect(array_values($this->additionalColumns));
        } else {
            foreach ($this->additionalColumns as $name => $additionalColumn) {
                if (!is_string($name)) {
                    $name = $additionalColumn;
                }
                if (in_array($name, $columns)) {
                    if (($key = array_search($name, $columns)) !== false) {
                        unset($columns[$key]);
                    }
                    $this->query->addSelect($additionalColumn);
                }
            }
            if (is_null($oldColumns)) {

                $this->query->addSelect($columns);
            }
        }

        return parent::getModels($columns);
    }

}
```

after that you can edit your model like this:

```php
class User extends Model {
    ...
    use App\Classes\AdditionalColumnsTrait;

    protected function getAdditionalColumns() {
        return [
            'siblings' => DB::raw(siblings(id) as siblings)),
        ];
    }
    ...
}
```

now your `siblings` column will be selected by default.
Also you have the option to select only specific columns.
If you don't want to select the additional columns you can use: `User::find(['users.*'])`.

Perhaps it is a solution for you.

Comment: Actually, I want to append `siblings(id) as `sibling`` to the eloquent attributes, apart from whatever it is getting from db